# Cartoon about aliens marooned on Earth

Tags: story-identification, aliens, cartoon

The basic concept of this show was that several aliens (who seem to be of different species) crashed the ship they crewed on Earth and had gone into hiding from humanity in a rundown house, possibly for years. I remember the following three:

Edno- considers himself the leader of the group, speaks with a stuffy British accent and believes himself to be a great intellectual.

A gluttonous, impulsive alien the others called Gorgeous (though he was anything but).

A third alien with two heads, whose name I don't recall.

The show opened with a short song summarizing the concept, sung by Iggy Pop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be: [Space Goofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Goofs), and yep -- the theme was 'Monster Men' done by Iggy Pop.

The gluttonous one was Gorgious Klatoo, Edno is actually Etno Polino, and the two-headed one was Stereo Monovici.

See if this seems familiar: